# LDAP password says expired when it is not - how do I fix that?

Tags: ldap

I'm using LDAP authentication on an application.  When logging in, I'm being told that my LDAP password has expired.  I've verified in Active Directory that it is set to 'never expire'.  Does anyone know what caused this issue and how it can be fixed?  CH

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the Security event log of the LDAP server you're connecting to. If the computer's Auditing settings include Account Logon event success and failure, you should get more information as to why the account is apparently locked out.

You may also want to try logging in with the support tool LDP.EXE.

The exact error may change the meaning too - the application may be interpreting any logon failure to indicate that the account password has expired.

Between auditing and network captures, you'll probably be able to find out what's working and what's not.